# PyMongo matching JavaScript regular expression objects

Tags: javascript, regex, pymongo

I'm trying to find a way to express a JavaScript regular expression in pymongo. I cannot use regex with a the $in operator according to the documentation. The code below will not work because the items in the list are not recognized obviously. Wondering how I can express the list items such that they are recognized as JS regular expressions in python. Appreciate the help

```
cursor = db.requests.aggregate([
            {'$match':
                {
                    '_id': {'$in':  [/^a/, /^A/]}
                }
            }
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want to use js regExp in pymongo instead of python regExp?

Comment: @AnhTuanNguyen I did try a solution involving python regExp and seems to work. Thanks for your suggestion/question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
lst = ['^a', '^A']

cursor = db.requests.aggregate([
{'$match':
   {
      '_id': {'$in':  [re.compile(x) for x in lst]}
   }
}])
```

Comment: Wow..never would have thought of doing that. Thanks!